# Two Level vertex Interpolation using GLSL 4.4

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I have a huge model (one million vertices), and some predefined control handles to deform this model. The control handles are in 2 levels, the positions of handles level-2 (around 10K) are the weight combination of handles level-1 (less than 1K). 
The model vertices positions are weight combination of handles level-2.

It could be illustrate like this:

```
  Handle-level-1 ( size <1000 )
              |
              |
        (interpolation #1)
              |
              |
              V
  Handle-level-2 ( size = 10K )
              |
              |
        (interpolation #2)
              |
              |
              V
       Model(size = 1M)
```

I am try to implement this 2 interpolation using GLSL, and currently there are two options in my mind:

[1] Use compute shader to compute the interpolation #1 (Handles Level-2), while Handles Level-1 can pass to GPU as uniform variables, and save Handles-Level-2 into a texture. Then I pass the interpolation weights/indexes as vertex attributes, and compute the model vertices position using vertex shader(interpolation #2).

[2] I allocate one buffer in GPU memory, and I also create vertex shader to compute interpolation #1 (Handles Level-2), then use TransformFeedback() to save the Handles Level-2 into buffer. To compute final models, I create vertex shaders, which can access complete Handles Level-2 buffer, and do the interpolation #2.

I have some concerns about both approaches above, so I am asking for some opinion:

**Approach (1):**

(a) The handles level-2 are vertex positions, which are float numbers, so can these float number be packed into an texture or image?

(b) If can not, which data structure is good for saving handles level-2, and accessible by vertex shaders that do interpolation #2? **Each shader have to access total handle level-2 data in this case.**

**Approach (2):**

(a) Can one piece of GPU memory (buffer store handles level-2) be accessible for **all vertex shaders** at the same time?

(b) If there are some memory can be accessed by all vertex shaders, will it cause some performance issue? because the vertex shaders try to access the data not in share memory or register of processes

**If either approaches can not work out, it there any possible solution for my case?**

Comment: Control handles? Sounds a lot like control points, since you are dealing with OpenGL 4.4 here, you might consider tessellation shaders.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andon :) Yes, it can be said control points. I am not quite familiar with tessellation shaders, maybe it's a possible way to make it work. Thanks for giving the idea :)